# Javascript page refresh to base URL, stripping query string, on browser resize -

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

**I'm using this piece of javascript code to refresh the browser when the user resizes it**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
  if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
  window.RT = setTimeout(function()
  {
    this.location.reload(true); /* false to get page from cache */
  }, 200);
});
</script>
```

It works fine, except - the page I'm using has a query string with certain values, like:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?w=123&h=456
```

What I'd like is the same functionality but to have the page refresh to the URL *without* the query string (or at least without its values).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since location is an object ,you can change the property 'href' to whatever you like , for example you can change the new location and assign it to the href property:

```
your current location is : http://www.example.com/index.php?w=123&h=456
```

when you need to refresh the page without the query string, you can do this: `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/index.php"` 
hope helps,
good luck

Comment: Sometimes simple things appear more complicated than they are.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.location = window.location.pathname` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you to redirect the page to root domain, then use `window.location.origin`. If you want to include the script name too then use `window.location.origin` and `window.location.pathname`. So your `redirect` can be replace with

```
window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```

Comment: The redirect is to the site root as it happens.  I'll get laughed to scorn I guess but I don't know how the new version would look with the amendment

Comment: I have no doubt these are correct answers but I cannot visualise how the script would work with such amendments.  A working example would help me.

Comment: to avoid errors in Typescript, because you can't assign a string to window.location, you can do this with `window.location.assign(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname);`